# pytest tmp_path unit tests do not completely clean up after themselves

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

The `pytest` `tmp_path` leaves behind directories, and this appears to be by design. From reading the documentation https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization seems the suggestion is to use yield and delete the file, but for instance, this test file, run on mac os/x

```
import os
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def config_ini(tmp_path):
    filename = tmp_path / "config.ini"
    fout = open(filename, "w")
    fout.write("myfile")
    fout.close()
    yield filename
    os.unlink(filename)


def test_fn(config_ini):
    fin = open(config_ini, "r")
    assert fin.read() == "myfile"
```

Does indeed delete the temporary file, but it leaves behind a lot of directories, like, after running this 7 times in a row, I see

```
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-5
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-5/test_fncurrent
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-5/test_fn0
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-current
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-6
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-6/test_fncurrent
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-6/test_fn0
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-7
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-7/test_fncurrent
/private/var/folders/ls/l1zf4tmn6njb4xht7sft96680000gp/T/pytest-of-davidsc/pytest-7/test_fn0
```

Which matches the documentation, pytest just keeps the last 3 tests.

However, I'm used to the school of though that a unit test should completely clean up after itself, and this test did not. I suppose I could do

```
yield filename
shutil.rmtree(filename.parent)
```

but now I feel like I'm messing with pytests mechanism and I might screw things up (like did I delete the soft link `pytest-current` as well? Or leave that dangling and pointing to something its not supposed to?).

The thing that makes me nervous about not cleaning up, is when these tests get run distributed - or two separate processes are running the tests that don't talk to one another, is pytest going to "figure it out?", get those one up counters right and not give me collisions? I'm tempted to abandon this pytest `tmp_path` fixture and fallback on `tempfile`, but I was so proud of myself for embracing this "new" technology :)

Answer (score 0):

I started a discussion at the pytest github repo that is getting some traction for those interested - probably a better place for this question https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/10325